# Can the word "A well person" be used?

Tags: word-choice

*Edited*

I've seen the word "a well person" in my school examination meaning a person who is not currently sick, can the word *well* be used as an adjective like that? Is "a well being person" more preferable? And how do we normally use the word *well* before a noun.

Comment: I've voted to re-open, because I think it could well be difficult for a *learner* to appreciate that idiomatically, very few native speakers would casually use the word ***well*** before a noun the same way we use, say, ***healthy*** or ***fit***. And although the slightly different usage *"I am **not** well"* is still perfectly natural, I myself am in no doubt that the non-negated *"I am well"* would normally be seen as dated/formal today.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This question only helps them learn that if they read your comment. Which I'm hoping they do. And/or we have a better answer posted.

Comment: @jimsug: Yeah - it's gratifying to see that three others have already endorsed my re-open vote. I don't know if that includes *you* (which might seem rather odd, since you were one of the original closevoters), but I think if all he had to go on were the existing answers on a closed question, a learner would end up seriously misinformed. For example, there's nothing remotely unusual about gardeners wishing to have *healthy plants*, but who ever heard of ***a well plant***?

Comment: @FumbleFingers So how actually is it used before a noun? Is it okay?

Comment: "a well being person" is incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking whether well can be used **attributively** (as in "a well person") and not just **predicatively** ("she is well").  A great question!

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (CGEL)* on page 560 includes *well* among those adjectives that do **not** appear attributively, with only a few exceptions.  Here's what they wrote:

> *Well* is used attributively in the construction *He's not a well man*, but in general it is excluded from attributive use: compare **his well mother*.

The exception mentioned in CGEL is specific to the negative phrase ***is not a well X***, where ***X*** refers to a type of animate being (typically a person, though an animal is also possible).  Here are some examples  from [*The Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)*](http://corpus2.byu.edu/coca/):

> 1. Just an opinion, but he**'s not a well person**.
> 2. Bear in mind how I**'m not a well woman**.
> 3. A plan was also floated to run him as Taft's vice presidential candidate, on the presumption Taft **was not a well man** and quite likely to die in office.
> 4. I**'m not a well woman**, Mary.
> 5. Mr. Cheskis, that orange cat **is not a well cat**. It should go to the ASPCA.

And you will find a few similar exceptions, including phrases like "a well-woman visit" where *well* is apparently an attributive modifier in a larger attributive phrase, but in general *well* does not appear attributively.  What's more, these few exceptions we do find aren't particularly common.  If you'd like to remember the simplified rule **never use *well* attributively**, it would serve you just fine.

Your phrase *<sup>?</sup>a well-being person* is unnatural.  [*Well-being*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/well-being), generally speaking, will be taken as a single noun, and it won't be understood the way you intended.

---

*In this answer, the * symbol indicates that a phrase is ungrammatical, while the <sup>?</sup> symbol indicates that a phrase is questionable.*

Comment: A well-woman means a women who is healthy but still attend a health check. And in those examples the word *well* means good, right? "He is not a well person" is just the same as "he is not a good person ".

Comment: Hmmm. I think I disagree.  In the very specific case the asker is asking about, where *well* is in parallel construction to *ill* or *sick*, I think it does fly. e.g. "A sick person may take the elevator, but a well person is expected to climb the stairs."

Comment: @SantiSantichaivekin I've always construed the "well-woman" in "a well-woman check" to mean not that the woman was well, but that the check was to ensure her wellness.  Not sure where that leaves you.

Comment: @SantiSantichaivekin Re _And in those examples the word well means good, right? "He is not a well person" is just the same as "he is not a good person."_  Oh boy, this is tricky.  In this usage "is not a well person" **denotes** "is mentally ill", but **connotates** that they're a bad person.  This is an example of what we call the "stigma of mental illness", and the use of the language of health to cast aspersions on people's characters.  So, no, it does not mean "good"... except that deep down, yes, that is what is being implied.

Comment: +1 This is exactly the kind of answer I was hoping for when I voted to reopen. @Santi: I suggest you *never* use "well" attributively. Partly *because* it's unusual, there's no consensus about what it means or implies. For example, I totally disagree with Codeswitcher's point above, and I have never heard *"He is not a well person"* in my life. I have heard *"He is not a well **man**"*, meaning *"He is **chronically** ill"* (physically, not mentally), but ***woman*** is rare there because of associations with "Well woman clinics".

Answer (score 1):

In this context, *well* is indeed an adjective, and it means *not ill* or *healthy*. It is much more commonly used in British English than American English, though it is valid and correct in both dialects.

Dictionaries:

- [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/well_5)
- [Oxford Learner's](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/well_2)
- [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/well)

Comment: There are also *well person health checks*, tests performed when a person is well, not sick or injured. Usually its some kind of preventive care.

Comment: Question updated^ ^

Comment: I have to disagree with *more commonly used in British English than American*. Checking prevalence in NGrams for [a well person](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+well+person&year_start=1930&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20well%20person%3B%2Cc0) suggests this usage is 2-3 times more common in the US corpus than the British one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was referring to the general use of the adjectival *well* as *healthy*, not the construct *well person* specifically. Indeed, my linked dictionary entries specify that *well* in this sense is rarely if ever used immediately before nouns. In the US we typically would say *good*, *fine* or *healthy*, not *well*, to answer *how are you feeling?* whereas I encountered *well* as the adjective of choice in England.

Comment: If by "general use" you mean *predicatively* ("He is well" = "He is in good health"), my gut feel (which seems to be backed up by NGrams) is that this form was indeed more common in BrE a couple of centuries ago. But it's fallen farther and faster in BrE than AmE since then, and although it's now somewhat dated/formal/uncommon everywhere, it now seems to be (slightly) more likely in AmE (which I feel has always been linguistically more conservative and slow to change, apart from specifically in respect of *spelling* because of Webster).