# 'Who is who' or 'Which is which'?

Tags: word-choice

Read this sentence:

> There are good people who will help you. There are bad people who'll cheat you. But you never know **who is who** or **which is which?**

My vote is for 'who is who' but then if I think twice, 'which is which' also fits! I'm confused.

Comment: Actually I wanted to ask something similar, why we say: which one of you did it? And not use who.

Comment: @LucianSava no, we say *who did it?* :)

Comment: "which one of you did it?" is incorrect?

Comment: @LucianSava no, it's not incorrect but the former one is short and straight! *Who* implies to any number of people in front of you. Why use superfluous words then?

Comment: Both phrases can be used but I'd go with 'who' because, who is USUALLY associated with people and which is USUALLY associated with things. Like- "Which ice-cream you like?" and not "who ice-cream you like"  .

Comment: @Invoker I also think the same but then if we use *which*, it can be applied to the *group (bad or good)* that contains people. That way, it sounds okay. Something like *which (group of) students scored A++ should sit in left.*

Comment: Yes, because towards a group of people we cannot use 'who'; *who group of students scored A++?* sounds lol.. but I think most of the time you should be able to make it out form the context just like you did in your question.

Comment: @Maulik, this one is for you: http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1350029, to sustain your down vote

Comment: @LucianSava I said both are okay. And you jumped too early to the conclusion. I did not downvote your answer ;) I generally prefer leaving out the answers from voting rather click on the lower button.

Comment: @MaulikV, it dosn't matter anyway.

Comment: @LucianSava Actually it should. I always ask the downvoter to give a reason. After all, it's learning. Note that most of my answers (even selected!) are downvoted leaving no comments - http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23803/can-the-word-a-well-person-be-used/23805#23805

Comment: I noticed that of you but I never saw that you received an answer. Few brave men are here. Most are hiding behind the computer and down vote.

Comment: @LucianSava yes I agree. I tried a lot to get into it and fix it somehow. But that's how this site works. Not even moderators have access to it I guess. The site **should** have some solution to this. Many simply love *clicking* the lower button without being sure.

Answer (score 1):

You’ll never know which one is good and which one is bad.

Edit:

You also can say:

Who is bad and who is good.

In first case you will have a more precise reference, in the second is more general, because who may be singular or plural, while which one is precise.

Answer (score 1):

**Who is who** refers to the *people*: there are good *people* and bad *people*.

**Which is which** would be frowned upon in this case by some people, I guess, but it could refer to the *good* and the *bad*. Semantically you are then talking about "good people" and "bad people" as impersonal concepts, I dare say that is not standard...

To avoid confusion, just use **who** when talking about people - and in the example phrase, most will read it as just that.

Of course, there is some confusion, because a slight change in the sentence would make **who** wrong, and **which** the only option:

> There are good events that will advance. There are bad events that will set you back. But you never know which is which!
>
> ---
>
> As for the question in the comment, what about "which one of you did it?"... now that *is* a good question indeed. Of course, you can avoid the whole issue as Maulik V. indicated, but that's just the easy way out, no?

My guess is that *which one* indicates we are picking one out of a group of objects. Consider:

> Which one of you rascals did it?
>   Which of you rascals did it?
>   Which rascal did it?
>   Which one of you did it? *"one" implies (or even takes on the role of) rascals or a substitute!*
>   Which of you did it? *rascals or a substitute is implied!*
>   Who of you did it? *no implied part here!*
>   Who did it?

Answer (score 0):

I think that, for **who is who** we emphasize/concentrate on the person who helped/cheated us; the **which is which** is for the action we received.